# Is it not possible to use the CLI, bash in this case, to find a set, take a set, move it, and not have to write a library to do so

Tags: bash, find, bsd

I thought this would be more of a one liner to be honest.

Pretty simple in notion:
using `find` on Mac OS X, locate files that meet a criteria, in my case:
all file and directories in a directory:
`find ~/Downloads +time1000s`

That finds what I need, then I run a conditional, if a dir exists, delete it, if not, create it:
mkdir -p ~/.Trash/safe-to-delte-these-old-files

This means I need to add print0 to my find as files will have spaces, and I want to move, not copy but either way, there is a source, and a destination, and I am getting stuck:

https://gist.github.com/5c0tt/5a2c1fd39ae99d6fca05
Line 27 and 26 seem to cause me issues, I am stuck.

Suggestions on everyone from line 1 to the end.  I am trying to hard to do this with POSIX in mind, but i can't even get variables to work then.

It seems BSD does not work the exact same way as other shells and what arguments they accept, which is why I am trying to be more POSIX, as I was told it should run anywhere then.

Thank you.

Comment: What about those two lines is not working exactly? What is happening? And neither `-print0` nor `xargs -0` are portable as far as I know. You can do both in portable ways though I believe with some more effort.

Comment: keep in mind that POSIX compliance is a minimal (and common) feature set, where as many utilities features vary by OS version, and can be considered as extra features. Not all `find` versions support `-print0` and there are 100s of other variants across utilties and OS versions. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Took a glance at your git link, a couple of remarks if I may (still a **noob** tbh so may be irrelevant) :

`dir_to_clean="/Users/my_username/Downloads"` should probably be `dir_to_clean="/Users/$current_user/Downloads"` unless you actually have a literal `/Users/my_username/Downloads` folder.

Instead of `cd`'ing into your users directory and since you have hardcoded the path to that directory, you could use `pushd` & `popd` instead in order to build a stack of directories.

**To answer your question**, to capture files with spaces in the name for removal you could use something like :

```
find $dir_to_clean -not -name . +time1000s -exec mv -- {} ~/.Trash/
```

**Could be something like this** :

```
# Initialise variables, user, source to clean, destination
user=$(whoami);
src="/Users/$user/Downloads";
dest="~/.Trash/safe_to_delete";

# Move to directory to clean, not necessary, but if you really want to
pushd $src;

# Check if the destination exists, if not, create it 
if [ ! -d $dest ]; then
    mkdir -p $dest;
else
    echo "destination already exists";
fi

# Find all the file to move then move them
find . -not -name . +time1000s -exec mv -- {} "$dest/" \;

# Return to previous working directory 
popd;
```

`pushd` the `$src` directory onto the stack. `find` all the files in the now current directory `.`, `-not -name .` in order to avoid trying to trash the `.` & `..` folders, `--` tells `find` to stop parsing command line options (in cas your file/folder is named i.e. *-myfile.txt*), `exec mv` all of the arguments to `$dest`. `popd` the still current directory off of the stack. `man find` (`/exec`) for more details.

**Note** : It is also interesting to know that the difference of execution time between the `-exec` option versus results being piped into `xargs` can and will often be quite dramatic. Also, if your are actually sure that those files are safe_to_delete, then delete them instead of moving them (`-exec rm -- {} $dest/`). With all that said, you were correct, one liner.

**Further reading** :
http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/using_exec_option_and_xargs_in_find.shtml